# apple script create new rule for mail, to activate apple script

Tags: macos, email, applescript

Okay so I want to create a apple script that creates a new rule in the mac mail app where if I write a new email and the content of the mail is "Start applescript", I want  a apple script to start.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
tell application "Mail"
set newRule to make new rule at end of rules with properties {name:"Apple script rule", forward message:""}
tell newRule
    make new rule condition at end of rule conditions with properties {rule type:message content, qualifier:does contain value, expression:"Start applescript"}
end tell
```

end tell

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to really achieve .

But the ***forward message:*** property cannot be blank i.e ""

You must have something there or the script will fail.

Answer (score 0):

This will work; however, while the rule works fine, every successive time you run this it doesn't do so well, and seems to try to add the stuff to the first rule it created. It does create the one rule though, so there's that.

Change the path (last thing on the second line), to the path to the script youre trying to run.

```
tell application "Mail"
    set newRule to make new rule at end of rules with properties {name:"Woohoo rule", forward message:"data@data.gov", run script:(POSIX file "/Users/Paul/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.mail/spam")}

    tell newRule
        make new rule condition at end of rule conditions with properties {rule type:message content, qualifier:does contain value, expression:"run applescript"}
    end tell

end tell
```